# Xpages creating an attachment file. Read Mode Only.

Tags: xpages

Is their a way to create an Attachment file which allow user to preview (Read mode =for example PDF format), and does not allow user to right click Copy it for personal use inside the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean with "read mode" that a user can only read an attachment but not download it then the answer is no. That's not possible. Even showing an attachment's content as HTML wouldn't help as it would be still possible to print the page and save it as pdf (in more modern browsers).

If you mean with "read mode" that a user can read and download attachments but not change the attachments in Domino document then yes: use Authors fields or don't add upload controls to your XPage.